# Which EU country has the most violent police force?

Tags: european-union, statistics, reference-request, police

I hope this is the right sub to post this in.

I am looking for a peer-reviewed study which compares the number of violent incidences committed by police officers against civilians in different EU countries. I don't want to include the military police that are present in some countries.

I have spent a bit of time searching on Google Scholar, but haven't come up with any good papers. Can someone point me towards some reliable literature? I am not really interested in people's opinions or anecdotes!

Comment: It can't be the Dutch, seeing they aren't even allowed tasers because it would "invite violence".

Comment: I meant EU - I've edited the post

Comment: Is there a specific definition of "unlawful violent offenses" you have in mind? Since the use of force by police is rarely prosecuted, there are lots of violent actions that are not technically unlawful. If you look at prosecution rates, you might find the countries with the best police departments (because they accurately prosecute violent officers) not the most violent ones (who ignore violence).

Comment: Good point. I guess I should drop the word 'unlawful', since as you said, violence committed by the police force against a citizen may be lawful. I am interested in a proxy measure for 'which police force in the EU is most willing to use violence against their citizens'

Comment: A very rough starting point is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_killings_by_law_enforcement_officers_by_country - of course who knows: Perhaps the three killed in Finland were *really* bad guys and it was self-defense? And the list is incomlete to begin with

Comment: It would also be nessessary to compare the brutality, and not just the numbers. Here is an example of relative few but brutal attacks by police: https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2014/04/impunity-excessive-force-and-links-extremist-golden-dawn-blight-greek-police/

Comment: The question needs work.  Every arrest in which the suspect is handcuffed is violent (putting handcuffs on someone without consent is common assault, if you aren't making an arrest)  there are degrees of violence that counting doesn't reflect.  And you need to consider justification.  A police force may have a high number of killings because of violence in society means that officers are more often under threat and find that they have to defend themselves.  Do you intend to include defensive violence?

Comment: It would be useful to separate out the ex-Soviet block countries, which are still gradually adapting to civil society, from the established Western European ones.  France's CRS riot police is mooted to have *Cons, Racistes et Salauds* (Dumb Racist and Jerks) as a basis for its acronym.  Not entirely without reason.  Pinning it all on the East European ones makes the Western ones look entirely too good.  Re. what @Divisiban says, that's an entirely true effect.  Sweden leads in rape statistics, for example but no one would seriously believe other countries are much better.

Comment: I think a meaningful question *should* include military-style forces as long as they are employed domestically in peacetime. Anything else would distort the numbers.

Comment: @o.m.: I suspect this q is exceedingly hard to answer if the latter is included. How does one count, e.g. the Greek (mostly military) border forces battling would-be immigrants at their border recently etc. Those incidents aren't likely to be individually reported etc. Somewhat similar story with the event in the Spanish enclaves. The press might write about a big event there, but there will usually not be individual complaints.

Comment: @Fizz, then perhaps exclude border incidents, but not militarized law enforcement inside the borders? I think that excluding e.g. the French National Gendarmerie or the Italian Carabineri would be distorting in any incident-per-capita comparison.